# Using NuGet for Universal Windows Store App development

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, dll, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to use precompiled NuGet packages, like zlib, for WinRT Universal App development. Everything installs and compiles just fine, but running app ends up with "Unable to locate DLL" exception. Apparently, **zlib.dll** ends up copied into **AppX\bin\v120\Win32\Debug\dynamic\cdecl** instead of just **AppX**. If I manually copy .dll to **AppX** folder, everything works as a charm. What am I doing wrong? How to make .exe load a library in the correct subfolder or make packager copy a .dll into application root folder?